# Setup MarkLogic Cluster 9.6

Tags: marklogic

I set up three servers for the local-disk failover.  All forests are connected to the database from three servers. 
To test cases for the following

Database: I created the testDB database on server1

Test case1: shutdown server1
issue: could not start Admin GUI.

Test case 2: shutdown server 2 or server 3

I can open admin browser on server1 on test case2.  Not sure why my test case 1 fails. is it because of the primary node?

```
Connect Database   server1 forests   server2 forests     Server3 forests
      testDB           DB-s1-f1          DB-s2-f1            DB-s3-f1
      testDB           DB-s1-f2          DB-s2-f2            DB-s3-f2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tyler mentioned, setting up replicas for your application database forests is only part of the fail over setup.

For successful fail over, you must also have at least one replica of the Security forest, as well as App Services forest and possibly others depending on your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to tell with out more information. Each database also has a security, triggers, scheme and modules database that is assigned to that database and those also have to have fail over forests setup on them. Have you setup a replica on them? I’d start by looking at the security database.

Comment: I think you meant 'Each cluster' instead of 'Each database'?

Comment: There is a dedicated section in the cluster guide about setting up failover for Security and auxiliary databases: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/config-both-failover#id_57935